# Regex For Finding ASP.Net page multiline comment

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

[image]I have Following code. In Visual studio it possible to find using regex and replace. so i am not able to generate regex for this code. Can anyone help me ?

```
<div class="span2 control-group">
    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblTeamName" Text="Team" runat="server" CssClass="control-label bold"></asp:Label>--%>
    <div class="controls">
        <%--<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbTeam" EmptyMessage="Select" runat="server" Width="160px"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbTeam_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>--%>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RF2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" Font-Size="X-Large"
            SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="ChartValidate1" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="rcbTeam"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regex needed for finding content in between of <%--content--%>

Comment: If you just want to uncomment the code, there's a button in the menu allowing to do so, or press the shortcut key (Ctrl E+U)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a regex you can use (please note the use of `*?` lazy quantifier so as not to overmatch):

```
<%--[\r\n\s\S]*?--%>
```

**Tested in Visual Studio 2012**:

[image]

Comment: Why have the lazy modifier on your `.*`?

Comment: When I remove it, I will only get 1 match, and there are 2 blocks in-between "<%--" and "--%>" in the input string.

Comment: now you can see my output, i am not getting multiline commented code. can you please help ?

Comment: No, i am not using this regex for C# code. i am using this regex in Find & replace section, so i can replace all commented code with white space in Whole Project at once. got my point ?

Comment: Ok, I see. I edited the answer, that regex `(?<=<%--)[\r\n\s\S]*?(?=--%>)` should be working alright then.

Comment: `[\S\s]*?` should be all you need . `\r` and `\n` are whitespace characters, so `\s` already includes them.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Did you try? I did. And... `[\S\s]*?` is NOT enough. Very strange. I am using VS2012.

Comment: Yes, it it working fine. but can you edit answer and given me solution where '<%--' and '--%>' is also replaced ...

Comment: @Hayat: Here you are, just converted the look-arounds into simple character sequences.

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), VS 2012 and later use the .NET flavor, so it should work.  But I don't have any of those versions installed, so I can't verify it.

Comment: @Hayat: FYI: `[\r\n\s\S]` can be reduced to `[\r\s\S]`, it seems the `[\s\S]` does not match `\r` only.